# Windows Server VM in Azure HTTP not working but HTTPS OK

Tags: windows, azure, http, http-status-code-404

Another admin in our company recently setup a windows azure VM.  Not sure what version of Windows, as I can't find that anywhere in the portal.  I setup IIS through the server manager dashboard, and it seemed to configure OK.  The site comes up locally, but only HTTPS.  There is no certificate installed, so I get the typical warnings.  But, with HTTP, I get nothing but an HTTP 404 not found error.  This is my first time doing this, but I have never encountered this error.  Any idea where I can find the settings to correct this?  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you could check as the following steps.

1. Please ensure you set your service listening on 80. You could check with command `netstat -ant|findstr 80`. Please refer to this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/149605/how-to-change-the-tcp-port-for-iis-services) if your IIS is not listening on 80.

2.Open port 80 on Azure NSG and open port 80 on Windows Firewall.

[image]

Comment: Here is what I found from that command:  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost

Comment: It's open on the windows firewall.  Where do I open it on azure?  Not sure why you have to do that.  I think it was already done, but can't find it on the azure portal.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ChrisA You should open port 80 on Azure NSG. Please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal).

Comment: @ChrisA I updated my answer. You could check your NSG, please you open port 80 on Inbound rules.

Comment: Ok.  I forgot that I did that a while ago.  It looks correct to  me:

Comment: Trying to upload a screenshot.  But, either serverfault has blocked me from doing that, or it just doesn't work.  The documentation says Ctrl-G  is a shortcut, but it definitely is not, as it is a search popup in chrome.

Comment: @ChrisA Could you access your web with private ip in your VM?

Comment: @ChrisA Please ensure you could access your web with private ip in your VM. Ensure you service is listening on 80 correctly. If you could not access it, you had better  check your IIS log firstly.

Comment: I cant access the service locally on the VM either through http or https, but can access the web from the VM.  I just configured a new VM, and i got http working, but this time not https.  LOL.  but, still can't view the service locally.  Getting 405 errors.  But, that  may be meaningless, as now I connected my site to the new IP but through http and it works perfectly.  Still, not sure how to set it up properly.  I have a more experienced https guy working on it.  But, still no go.  Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: Well.  It shouldn't be this difficult just to get IIS running in a VM, serving http and https.  It should be straight forward.  I'm guessing maybe there's a template to install somehow through powershell or?  I would be great to get a straightforward answer, and not just check all the basic settings that I've already checked.

Comment: @ChrisA Yes, you could. Maybe you could check this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34351.configure-iis-server-on-azure-virtual-machine-windows-server.aspx).